# Xcode Shell script invocation error : Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127

Tags: xcode, bash

I am having Shell script invocation error:

> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code
>   127

error when I try to archive my project. I was able to build normally without shell script error, if I checked "Run script only when installing" in build phases. Archiving has become an issue with or without the check in build phases. Getting this error constantly.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Three years ago for the question, and a reminder from end march this year. OK, I'll bite.

In general, a shell script ends with the exit-code that you want it to. So if your script contains:

```
exit 127
```

That would probably be the reason for the exit code.

However, certain exit-codes are standard and it is commonly understood that it is bad practice to use them. (table below is non-exhaustive)

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Catch-all for general errors, e.g. divide by zero etc. |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | Misuse of shell build-ins                              |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 126| Cannot execute command invoked                         |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 127|Illegal command/command not found                       |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 128|Illegal argument to exit (e.g. exit 3.14)               |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

So if there is no `exit 127` in the script, it is probably an illegal command. Does `/bin/sh` actually exist? (sounds trivial, but I've seen systems where it does not exist.) What does the script report when you run it by hand?